# AbstractMethodError For @BeforeAll when using SpringExtension.beforeAll

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, spring-boot-test

When trying to run my Spring Boot application Integration tests using Junit, I get the following error to do with the @BeforeAll tag and @AfterAll tags not being allowed to be used.

I was following this tutorial but was required to add a few things to my POM because Intellij wasn't picking up the Jupiter runner correctly:
https://info.michael-simons.eu/2018/06/18/maven-use-junit-5-with-spring-boot-for-unit-and-integration-tests/

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(Lorg/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ContainerExtensionContext;)V

at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:197)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassTestDescriptor.java:197)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:152)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:61)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:87)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:93)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:59)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Suppressed: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(Lorg/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ContainerExtensionContext;)V
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$null$7(ClassTestDescriptor.java:232)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$8(ClassTestDescriptor.java:232)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassTestDescriptor.java:232)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:168)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:96)
    ... 19 more
```

My Pom dependencies are:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- and the engine for surefire and failsafe -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Explicitly required for Intellij -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And my integration suite:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GameIntegrationTests {

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using JUnit 5 `M4` (i.e., milestone release 4) which is unsupported with that version of Spring Boot.

You should instead use JUnit Platform 1.1.1 and JUnit Jupiter 5.1.1 or later versions with Spring Boot 2.0.3.

Make sure you are also using version `2.19.1` of the Maven Surefire plugin as documented in the [JUnit 5.1.1 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.1/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven).

Comment: Using versions 1.1.1 and 5.1.1 did fix my problems but found I still needed to use a lower version for Maven Surefire, 19.1.0, due to maven not picking up my tests on version 2.22.0. 

I also need to update my version of Intellij from 16.0.3, to be able to run any of my junit 5 tests.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! And... sorry about recommending the wrong Surefire version.

Comment: FYI: I updated the answer to point to the User Guide for 5.1.1 with regard to the supported version of Surefire, which should be `2.19.1` (not `19.1.0` as you mentioned -- right?).

Comment: Yes, 2.19.1 is what I am using, not sure why I said 19.1.0. Apologises